# how to connect postgres database with Auth0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, heroku-postgres, auth0

When I connect heroku postgres database with Auth0 then i am getting below error.

```
could not connect to postgres db { [error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXXXXXXX", user "XXXXXX", database "XXXXXX", SSL off]
  name: 'error',
  length: 161,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '496',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication' }
[error] 28000 - undefined
```

I am using Auth0 so please find below  auth0 code with heroku database details and URL.

```
configuration.config_file = "postgres://username:password@host:port/DB_name"

function login (email, password, callback) {

  var conString = configuration.config_file;
  postgres(conString, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('could not connect to postgres db', err);
      return callback(err);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post the error messages if you get any.

Comment: Did you give the proper permissions to allow access to your database? The pg_hba.conf file is were the access permissions are seems like the IP of your server is not listed there or does not have proper permissions.

Comment: @yakiklein Could you please tell me that how to give permission when we access heroku database with auth0 ?

Comment: take a look at my answer below. Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: @GauravGupta how did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try to add '?ssl=true' to your conString. Heroku requires access via SSL for remote connections. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js (under "Remote Connections") for details.

Answer (score 2):

The code you write here runs in Auth0 (in the cloud). Which means you'll need to use a hostname or IP address Auth0 can connect to.

If you're using a hostname like `DBSERVER01` or an IP address like `10.10.5.1` these are only available within your network and auth0 will not be able to reach them.

Make sure you use the public IP address of your network (like `45.19.3.29`) or a public facing hostname (like `mydb01.mycompany.com`).

Comment: How to access heroku postgres database on local machine with auth0 ?

Comment: According this doc from Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku, you shouldn't hardcode the database URL or IP. You're supposed to fetch it via `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a your-app`. However, this is problematic when using auth0's database action scripts as they are sandboxed and don't allow network access. I haven't figured this out yet - has anyone else come up with a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this [document](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/postgresql.html) from ubuntu website. It explains how to install postgres database locally.

After installing postgres you will need to create a user and give it proper authentication.

Comment: thanks for this, I want to use heroku database on local with auth0. please see my code.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the fact that the OP is using heroku.